# Adding and removing elements in an array: An exercise

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking to fill an array a with the numbers 1 through 10 and take a random number from that array and add it to an array b and remove that element from array a. I would like to know the most efficient way of doing this. EDIT: (The exercise requires that I not have repeated values in the arrays and that the permutation is random each time the method is called.) Here is my method so far:

```
public int[] nextPermutation() {
    int capOne = 10;
    int capTwo = 10;
    int aSize = 0;
    int bSize = 0;


    int[] a = new int[capOne];
    int[] b = new int[capTwo];

    int upperBound = 11;
    Random generator = new Random();

    //fill initial array with 1 - 10
    for (int i = aSize; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = i + 1;
        //companion variable for sizing array
        aSize++;
    }

    //Create a random integer and add it to array b
    //Remove same integer from array a
    //Repeat and remove another random integer from the remaining integers in array a and    add it to b


        permuted = b;
        return permuted;
        }
```

I may be approaching this in an inefficient if not completely incorrect manner. If so, I'm sure you won't hesitate to tell me. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you better use a list

Comment: Given that the array contains ten elements, I doubt you need to worry about efficiency too much. Focus on correctness.

Comment: Hi StinePike. As in List list = Arrays.asList() or an ArrayList?

Comment: can you have repeated values?

Comment: No I cannot have repeated values. I should have specified that. My apologies.

Comment: You can use ArrayList or List.Any one of this you can use.

Comment: I agree that an ArrayList would be much easier to use. The exercise in the book I am reading asks for an array though.

Comment: Really, an Array is the wrong animal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
//randomly choose element
int index = (int) (Math.random() * aSize);
int dataFromA = a[index];

//"remove" it from A
aSize--;
for(int i = index; i<aSize; i++) {
    a[i] = a[i+1];
}

//"add" it to b
b[bSize] = dataFromA;
bSize++;
```

Only interesting part is removing from A, where you have to reduce the size before the cycle (or you can `i < aSize-1`, then decrement size)

I guess you *have to* use arrays since this is an excersice, but using `List` for this would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program producing random permutations, using swap. Well, I'm not sure which can produce a better result, but swap should be faster than add/remove to/from an array:

```
public int[] nextPermutation() {
    int cap = 10;
    int[] a = new int[cap];
    Random generator = new Random();

    //fill initial array with 1 - 10
    for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
        a[i] = i + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
        int j = generator.nextInt(cap);
        int x = a[j];
        a[j] = a[i];
        a[i] = x;
    }

    // You can reduce the size of the output array:
    // int output[] = new int[5];
    // System.arraycopy(a, 0, output, 0, 5);
    // return output;

    return a;
}
```